# How to simulate Chrome prerender/prefetch?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I test the behavior of a Chrome extension when prerender/prefetch occures? Specifically, I would like to see tabs.onReplaced and webNavigation.onTabReplced fired.

I have checked the chrome://net-internals/#prerender page, the prerender is enabled, but I never see it in use.

I use the latest version of Chrome (Version 63.0.3239.84).

Comment: Make sure `Use a prediction service to load pages more quickly` is enabled in browser settings and simply type something in the addressbar - the results page should get prerendered.

Comment: This settings is on, and it doesn't seem to be prerendered (events not fired as well).

Comment: Apparently, it was [deprecated](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/0nSxuuv9bBw/EMfaclV-AwAJ). Yep, omnibar prerendering aka *instant* was removed too: https://crbug.com/755921

Comment: What about onReplaced? Is it ever called?

Comment: Given the info in those links I don't see any reason why it should be invoked.

Comment: It seems that some kind of prerender still exists, but events are not called. For example, when I type gmail.com in the omnibar, the first onBeforeNavigate event (fired before pressing Return) contains non-existing tabId, which, I presume, is then replaced with the original tab. But it seems like only the content is swapped, and tabId of the visible tab is the same. By the way, is it the same in case of tabReplace? I mean, when replace happens, the id of the tab that is actually visible to the user remains the same, or the tab is swapped entirely?

Comment: When it swaps, it swaps entirely. The only thing that remains the same is the index in the tab strip.